# How do I calculate file size ignoring PDFs (or other binary files)?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

I would like to calculate the file size of a directory tree, but I want to ignore all PDFs and images as well. Essentially, I'm trying to figure out what the size of the text-only files are.

How can I do this?

<sub>Note: this is in a Linux environment, RedHat in particular</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Consider a directory structure as follows:

```
$ ls -sR1
.:
total 32
4 1/
4 2/
4 m
4 n
4 o
4 x.pdf
4 y.pdf
4 z.pdf

./1:
total 0

./2:
total 8
4 a/
4 p

./2/a:
total 4
4 q
```

Then to get a list of all files which do not match `*.pdf`, we can do

```
$ find . -type f \( ! -name '*.pdf' \)
```

whose expansion to also not match, say, `*.jpg` is rather obvious. Then use  `du` as follows:

```
$ du -c $(find . -type f \( ! -name '*.pdf' \))
4   ./o
4   ./m
4   ./n
4   ./2/a/q
4   ./2/p
20  total
```

where you might want to throw in a `-b` to get the apparent size in bytes rather than disk usage. `-c` gives out the grand total.

The limitations of this approach are:

1. It won’t work if your directory tree is very large, because

   - Because it scans the tree twice (`find` + `du`)
   - Because it feeds the output of `find` into `du` via the command line and is thus bounded by the maximum allowed size for that.
2. It will (in this naive approach) only match files based on their names, not their content.

You can overcome 1. by using `find` to execute `du` on each individual file and then use `awk` or something similar to add it all up. 2. might be solved by more intriguing checks in `find`, possibly based on the output of `file` for each file and matching it against a positive or negative list.